# Does MDC have a grid system?

Tags: material-design-lite, material-components

Does MDC have a grid system, something like Bootstrap's where you put columns inside rows with different widths depending on screen size.

If this is not yet supported (and/or not going to be) what's the official stand on the team on this thing, is MDL's grid the official supported to use?

Comment: Yea.   Where's the grid?  We supposed to just use flexbox now, or what?  Breakpoints?

Comment: I sympathise with this question, as it's not mentioned in the getting started etc.  Once you do find it, it's documented in a way which means thousands of people will spend thousands of hours figuring out how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.  Looks like it just hatched hours ago.  Looks like it behaves like MDL grid.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-layout-grid

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Material design’s responsive UI is based on a column-variate grid layout. It has 12 columns on desktop, 8 columns on tablet and 4 columns on phone.

https://material-io.cn/develop/web/components/grid-lists/